# Getting POST request from an HTML form into a Django database

Tags: python, html, django

i'm looking to implement a simple HTML form that passes a bunch of data to a Django backend which then stores it and displays it on another page. Unfortunately i can't seem to hook the back and front ends together. I'm relatively new to Django and this is the only bit really giving me grief
The HTML being used:

```
<form action="{% url 'jobs:send' job_id%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label>Job ID</label>
<input type="number" id="job_id">
<br>
<label>Store</label>
<select>
    {% for store1, store2 in STORE_CHOICES %}
        <option value="{{ store1 }}">{{ store2 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br>
<label>Department</label>
<select>
    {% for dept1, dept2 in DEPARTMENT_CHOICES %}
        <option value="{{ dept1 }}">{{ dept2 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br>
<label>Team Member</label>
<input type="text" id="team_member">
<br>
<label>Support Member</label>
<select>
    {% for supp1, supp2 in SUPPORT_CHOICES %}
        <option value="{{ supp1 }}">{{ supp2 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br>
<label>Job Details</label>
<textarea type="text" id="job_details" rows="4"></textarea>
<br>
<label>Job Status</label>
<select>
    {% for status1, status2 in STATUS_CHOICES %}
        <option value="{{ status1 }}">{{ status2 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<br>
<label>Feedback Given</label>
<textarea type="text" id="feedback_given" rows="4"></textarea>
<br>



<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

Below is my views.py file. I get the impression this is where my problem is but i can't seem to pass the information between the HTML and the functions correctly, even at all. I

```
def send(request, job_id):
list = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    #Do things

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs:create', args=(job_id,)))

def create(request,):
context = {
    'STATUS_CHOICES': Job.STATUS_CHOICES,
    'DEPARTMENT_CHOICES': Job.DEPARTMENT_CHOICES,
    'STORE_CHOICES': Job.STORE_CHOICES,
    'SUPPORT_CHOICES': Job.SUPPORT_CHOICES,
}
return render(request, 'jobs/create.html', context)
```

My "urls.py" file is as below

```
app_name = 'jobs'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /jobs/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /jobs/create/
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    # ex: /jobs/added/
    path('added/', views.added, name='added'),
    # ex: /jobs/5/
    path('<int:job_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # send POST data
    path('send/<int:job_id>', views.send, name='send'),
]
```

Can anyone identify the source of my issue? I have been scouring tutorials to try and gain a better understanding of the way the systems pass data between themselves but i can't seem to figure it out.
Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Python. I suggest you read PEP8, the Python style guide it will help you. All capitals are reserved for constants. Formatting is also very important in Python, your code, as is, would cause a syntax error.

Comment: @diek Hi there, i've managed to find a solution as below. I'm not necessarily new to python, but definitely to Django, so might have missed some bits and pieces copying and pasting code i thought was relevant. Thanks for your reply regardless, great to have it sorted!

Comment: Check out the Mozilla Django tutorial, highly recommend it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it myself, using example code from the the 15th or so tutorial i looked up. Turns out i didn't quite have a proper idea of how the responses worked. Working a treat now!